# Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder to create dataset to store Chinese Names

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to create a dataset in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder containing a list of Chinese Names and English Names, so I can map the Chinese Name by English Name.

I cannot change the database as I have read-only access, but I can upload files to SQL Server Reporting Services server side.

How can I store the Chinese Names in a rdl file or a shared dataset rsd?

Comment: the version is SQL Server 2014

Comment: For SQL Server 2016, they have enter data feature directly. I am wondering how they do this before? https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/archive/blogs/sqlrsteamblog/enter-data-feature-now-available-in-sql-server-2016-report-builder

Comment: You should edit your question rather than use the comments to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dataset with a query something like.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (NameEN nvarchar(256), NameCN nvarchar(256))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Dave', 'something'),
('Mary', 'something else'),
('Bob', 'something different')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

You will need a valid database connection but you won;t be saving anything to the database, it will only be visible in the report. You could do a similar thing with a shared dataset.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark below the vote up/down buttons to the left)